# How to apply collector if some condition holds?

Tags: java, java-8, collectors

I have some method which can merge List and produce `String`:

```
private static String merge(List<String> strs){
    // do some and return some String
}
```

I also have some list and some boolean flag:

```
boolean flag = //..
List<String> lst = //...
```

I want to produce a `List<String>`  which consists of all elements in `lst` if `flag == false` and `merge(lst)` if `flag == true`. I want to write some Collector which can do so.

```
lst.stream().collect(
   //Here I want Collectors.toList, or apply merge if flag == true
)
```

Is there a way to **concisely** craft such `Collector`?

Comment: Have you tried writing your custom `Collector` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html))? If so, can you share where your problems are?

Comment: @Zabuza My question is about a concise way? Writing custom collectors seems overkill for such case.

Comment: I did'nt get the problem. You say that you want to call `Collectors.toList` or `merge`, but they dont return the same type.

Comment: I would simply wrap an `if-else` around. In the `if-case` use `lst.stream().collect(Collectors.toList)` and in the `else-case` use `merge(strs)`.

Comment: What data type would you use to store the values returned from such an operation as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `merge` returns a `String` and the collector a `List<String>`. You can not combine both into one. You would need to use a custom container class like

```
public class Container {
    List<String> onePossibleResult;
    String otherPossibleResult;
}
```

You then would also need to create a custom `Collector` which is able to handle that custom `Container`. And I doubt that you would find that **concise**.

The next problem is that your `merge` function wants a `List<String>` and not `Stream<String>` or `String`. But at the point you want to apply it, inside the `collect` method, you receive `String` elements:

```
lst.stream().collect(Collector<? super T,A,R> collector);
```

Where:

- `R` - the type of the result
- `A` - the intermediate accumulation type of the Collector

And `T` which is the type of the elements contained in the `Stream<T>`, so `String` in this case, not `List<String>`.

---

I would simply wrap an `if-else` around, this only adds 3 lines of code:

```
if (flag) {
    String mergeResult = merge(lst);
} else {
    List<String> collectResult = lst.stream().collect(Collectors.toList);
}
```

Note that the `else-case` just produces a copy of the same list, you could simply do this instead:

```
List<String> collectResult = new ArrayList<>(str);
```

Comment: To be honest I don't see the reason in the ``else`` statement, you are just collecting the same list. Or I am missing something ?

Comment: @SchiduLuca Yes, I think so, it's a copy. However that is what OP asked for: '*Here I want Collectors.toList*'. But good that you highlight that.

Comment: @SchiduLuca It's not __the same__ list, it is a copy. But I agree `new ArrayList<>(lst);` would make more sense/is more readable.

Comment: It seems like the OP wants a list with the one merged string if flag is true. E.g. `final List<String> result = flag ? Arrays.asList(merge(lst)) : new ArrayList<>(lst)`

Comment: @msfoster I'm unsure, you may give it a try and post it as answer. Definitely is very concise.